# How to transfer efficiently data from one socket to another on windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, splice

On linux u can use `splice()` twice and two pipes in configuration:
`socketA -> pipeAB -> SocketB` + `socketB -> pipeBA -> SocketA` to transfer data more effectively than `read/write` combo. On the internet u can find answer that on windows u can use `TransmitFile` function for that purpose, but the description of that function say - transfer data from **physical file to socket**. I don't see how it can help in socket to socket data transfer. Can someone please explain it, or give other solution similar to linux one?

Comment: Are you looking for [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing like `splice()` on Windows for "descriptor-to-descriptor transfers" using sockets. You would have to read in data from a socket and then write out the data to the other socket/pipe/whatever, and vice versa. That being said, you might be able to do something with [Registered I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh997032(v=ws.11)) and sharing memory buffers, but I'm not sure.